# Python3: JSON to CSV

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have a JSON dict in Python which I would like to parse into a CSV, my data and code looks like this:

```
import csv
import json

x = {
"success": 1,
"return": {
    "variable_id": {
        "var1": "val1",
        "var2": "val2"
    }...

f = csv.writer(open("foo.csv", "w", newline=''))
for x in x:
    f.writerow([x["success"],
                '--variable value--',
                x["return"]["variable_id"]["var1"],
                x["return"]["variable_id"]["var2"])
```

However, since variable_id's value is going to change I don't know how to refer to in the code. Apologies if this is trivial but I guess I lack the terminology to find the solution.

Comment: `x` is not a JSON object, it's just a dict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `*` (unpack) operator to do this, assuming only the values in your `variable_id` matter :

```
f.writerow([x["success"],
           '--variable value--',
           *[val for variable_id in x['return'].values() for val in variable_id.values()])
```

The unpack operator essentially takes everything in `x["return"]["variable_id"].values()` and appends it in the list you're creating as input for `writerow`.

**EDIT** this should now work if you don't know how to reference`variable_id`. This will work best if you have several `variable_id`s in `x['return']`.

If you only have one `variable_id`, then you can also try this :

```
f.writerow([x["success"],
           '--variable value--',
           *list(x['return'].values())[0].values()])
```

Or

```
f.writerow([x["success"],
           '--variable value--',
           *next(iter(x['return'].values())).values()])
```

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was unclear but the issue is that I cannot use "variable_id", as it is not a constant, it will change for each x["return"], hence I don't know how to reference it. Perhaps there is a kind of placeholder/variable syntax I'm unaware of?

Comment: I've updated my answer so it would work if the key(s) in `x['return']` is(are) not constant(s). Something better may exist, but it should work. Of course, you can (should) use a generator instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you, this now works, except for it writes everything to the same row, any idea how to make it write each variable_id on separate ones?

Comment: You could probably do this in a single line : `f.writerows([[x['success'], '--variable value--', *vals] for vals in x['return'].values()])` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get variable_id's value using `x['success']['return'].keys[0]`.